# Putting the scrolling camera in a mini-window in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, window, surface, blit

I'm trying to create a game where the action is shown in a little box within the main screen object, freeing up the surrounding space for text and menus and what-not.  Since the map is larger than the allotted window, I coded a basic "camera" that follows the player around.  It mostly works, but I'm having trouble "trimming off" the area outside of this window.

Here's the relevant bits of code (EDITED to provide Working Example):

```
import pygame, os, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

RIGHT = 'RIGHT'
LEFT = 'LEFT'
UP = 'UP'
DOWN = 'DOWN'

class Camera():
    def __init__(self, screen, x_ratio = 1, y_ratio = 1, x_offset = 0, y_offset = 0):
        self.screen = screen.copy()
        self.rec = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.rec.width *= x_ratio
        self.rec.height *= y_ratio
        self.x_offset = x_offset
        self.y_offset = y_offset
    def get_pos(self):
        return (self.x_offset - self.rec.x, self.y_offset - self.rec.y)
    def get_window(self):
        w = pygame.Rect(self.rec)
        w.topleft = (0 - self.rec.x, 0 - self.rec.y)
        return w
    def move(self, x, y):
        """Move camera into new position"""
        self.rec.x = x
        self.rec.y = y
    def track(self, obj):
        while obj.rec.left < self.rec.left:
            self.rec.x -= 1
        while obj.rec.right > self.rec.right:
            self.rec.x += 1
        while obj.rec.top < self.rec.top:
            self.rec.y -= 1
        while obj.rec.bottom > self.rec.bottom:
            self.rec.y += 1

class Map:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.rec = pygame.Rect(0,0,self.width,self.height)

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200,200,200), self.rec)

class Obj:
    def __init__(self, char, x = 0, y = 0, width = 0, height = 0):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.rec = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
        self.cur_map = None
        self.timers = {}

        #Dummying in chars for sprites
        self.char = char

        self.x_dir = 1
        self.y_dir = 1
        self.speed = 1
        self.moving = False        

    def move(self):
        if self.x_dir != 0 or self.y_dir != 0:
            new_x = self.rec.x + (self.x_dir*self.speed)
            new_y = self.rec.y + (self.y_dir*self.speed)
            new_rec = pygame.Rect(new_x, new_y, self.width, self.height)

            #Keep movement within bounds of map
            while new_rec.left < self.cur_map.rec.left:
                new_rec.x += 1
            while new_rec.right > self.cur_map.rec.right:
                new_rec.x -= 1
            while new_rec.top < self.cur_map.rec.top:
                new_rec.y += 1
            while new_rec.bottom > self.cur_map.rec.bottom:
                new_rec.y -= 1

            self.rec = new_rec

    def set_dir(self, d):
        self.x_dir = 0
        self.y_dir = 0
        if d == LEFT:
            self.x_dir = -1
        elif d == RIGHT:
            self.x_dir = 1
        elif d == UP:
            self.y_dir = -1
        elif d == DOWN:
            self.y_dir = 1

    def set_moving(self, val = True):
        self.moving = val

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_size = (800, 600)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.screen_size)
        self.map_screen = self.screen.copy()
        self.title = 'RPG'
        pygame.display.set_caption(self.title)

        self.camera = Camera(self.screen, 0.75, 0.75)#, 10, 75)

        self.fps = 80
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.debug = False
        self.bg_color = (255,255,255)
        self.text_size = 18
        self.text_font = 'Arial'
        self.text_style = pygame.font.SysFont(self.text_font, self.text_size)
        self.key_binds = {LEFT : [K_LEFT, K_a], RIGHT : [K_RIGHT, K_d], UP : [K_UP, K_w], DOWN : [K_DOWN, K_s],
                          'interact' : [K_RETURN, K_z], 'inventory' : [K_i,  K_SPACE], 'quit' : [K_ESCAPE]}

        self.player = Obj('p', 0, 0, 10, self.text_size)     

    def draw(self, obj):
        char = obj.char       
        self.draw_text(char, obj.rec.x, obj.rec.y, screen = self.map_screen)

    def draw_text(self, text, x, y, color = (0,0,0), screen = None):
        textobj = self.text_style.render(text, 1, color)
        textrect = textobj.get_rect()
        textrect.x = x
        textrect.y = y
        if screen == None:
            """Use default screen"""
            self.screen.blit(textobj, textrect)
        else:
            screen.blit(textobj, textrect)

    def play(self):
        done = False
        cur_map = Map(800, 800)
        self.map_screen = pygame.Surface((cur_map.width, cur_map.height))
        self.map_screen.fill(self.bg_color)

        bg = pygame.Surface((cur_map.width, cur_map.height))
        cur_map.draw(bg)

        self.player.cur_map = cur_map

        while not done:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key in self.key_binds[LEFT]:
                        self.player.set_dir(LEFT)
                        self.player.set_moving()
                    elif event.key in self.key_binds[RIGHT]:
                        self.player.set_dir(RIGHT)
                        self.player.set_moving()
                    elif event.key in self.key_binds[UP]:
                        self.player.set_dir(UP)
                        self.player.set_moving()
                    elif event.key in self.key_binds[DOWN]:
                        self.player.set_dir(DOWN)
                        self.player.set_moving()

                elif event.type == KEYUP:
                    self.player.set_moving(False)


            if self.player.moving:
                self.player.move()

            self.camera.track(self.player)
            self.clock.tick()

            self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
            self.map_screen.blit(bg, (0,0))            
            self.draw(self.player)

            pygame.draw.rect(self.map_screen, (0,0,0), self.camera.rec, 1)
            #self.screen.blit(self.map_screen, (0,0), [0 - self.camera.rec.x, 0 - self.camera.rec.y, self.camera.rec.width, self.camera.rec.height])
            self.screen.blit(self.map_screen, self.camera.get_pos(), self.camera.get_window())
            pygame.display.flip()

game = Game()
game.play()
```

Moving the player past past the bounds of the camera's window causes the window to roll up completely and disappear.  I tried adjusting the blitting coordinates, as advised earlier, but it seems to only change the direction in which the window rolls up.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] so we can try to help?

Comment: Done. If you run it as-is you can now see for yourself exactly how the problem looks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your updated code, the blitting coordinates for `self.screen.blit(...)` are still changing: `self.camera.get_window()` changes value because `rec.x` and `rec.y` are values referring to the player position within the map. Hence you should define a constant minimap coordinate, this should be the same as the camera offset.

```
self.screen.blit(self.map_screen, (self.camera.x_offset,self.camera.y_offset), (*self.camera.get_pos(), self.camera.rec.width, self.camera.rec.height))
```

Change the `Camera().get_pos()` to:

```
def get_pos(self):
    return (self.rec.x, self.rec.y)
```

I believe I only changed the `self.screen.blit(...)` and stopped using or rewrote your Camera functions as you're confusing yourself with all the rec variables.

To illustrate it working amend the `Map().draw(screen)` to:

```
def draw(self, screen):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200,200,200), self.rec)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), (50, 50), 20, 2)
```

One tip as well don't draw the entire map at each loop, just the part that will be visible.

Comment: Tried it, but it seems to just reverse the direction of the roll-up.  I improved my code example so you can see it better in action.

Comment: @queenofthecapes I updated my answer to your latest code